# Contract ownership?

Tags: etherscan

I recently started an NFT collection called MetroView that includes 5 digital
Art pieces. Each piece has a 0x address.
“Who owns these addresses?  How do I access the holdings of the contract address?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you started the collection? Each site has its own way organizing NFTs. Usually a NFT is in a smart contract that has an address. A collection is several NFTs within the same contract or several contracts. Who owns them? It is likely the site that create them. It should be better if you contact their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

Initially whoever created those addresses is the owner and creator of those NFT. this is a struct of NFT item:

```
// contract owner might add different properties. this is the basic
struct NftItem{
    uint tokenId;
    uint price;
    // creator and owner are not same. creator someone who minted. creator does not change
    address creator;
    bool isListed;
  }
```

When you create an NFT, or (mint an NFT), you first upload the image to IPFS, and then you create a JSON file that includes metadata and the Uri of the uploaded image and finally you upload this JSON data to IPFS and you get the URi. When you mint the token, you basically store this URi on blockchain. This is the signature of mint token

```
 // passing the string of the Uri and price of how much you want to sell for
  function mintToken(string memory tokenURI,uint price) public payable returns (uint){}
```

When you sell this item, owner changes.

so those URIs are stored on the blockchain but only the owner of the contract can view those (or whoever the owner of the contract allows)